# PSpice for TI - adding a library

Tags: pspice

I want to use a transistor: Q2N2222, Which exists in the bipolar library in pspice. (I'm using pspice for TI)

however. I have found ZERO guides on how to actually add a new library to pspice. every guide is either outdated or simply not about what I need.

Please, help would be appreciated, I am looking for hours for a way.

Comment: Have you tried the manual (`F1`)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can add library on Pspice for TI but you can add part. If you are using TI Pspice Training pdf manual, see module 12 about importing 3rd party vendor models.